# Find address which called the method?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, addresses

How can a contract method find the address which invoked it?

Suppose I have a contract `A` with method `B`. I used `xyz` address to call method `B` then how can method `B` see `xyz` address.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `msg.sender` variable.  It's automatically available in the contract:

```
function hello() {
  address from = msg.sender;
}
```

More information in the [solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/miscellaneous.html#cheatsheet)

Comment: ```msg.sender``` would only return address of the direct caller, but if this caller a proxy contract it would not return an initial caller. The best suggestion so far is to to pass initial caller as a parameter https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/28977/23579

Answer (score 3):

Inside the contract you can use `msg.sender` to get the address of the caller. See [Block and Transaction Properties](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties) for the list of global variables.

> msg.sender (address): sender of the message (current call)