# Who is msg.sender when calling a contract from a contract

Tags: solidity, contract-design

When I call a function in my contract which calls another function in another contract. In the second called contract function who is msg.sender? the contract calling the second contract or my account?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just to add to Jesse's answer. `tx.origin` is *supposed to be* the account that signed a transaction. This sounds useful in principle, but in practice, it has been shown that the value can be spoofed.

That means you can only use `tx.origin` when you're interested in the user identity but security isn't a concern, so ... err .. never. It's possible such a use-case exists, but I've yet to see it.

You can successfully design things with the origin in mind, using `msg.sender` as the reliable input. Just pass it into functions in contracts further down the chain.

```
function callOther() public returns(bool success) {
  return other.doSomething(msg.sender);
}
```

and, in "Other",

```
function doSomething(address origin) public returns(bool success) {
  // origin is the original initiator
  // msg.sender is the contract that called this. 
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Spoofed? At the protocol level, or at the application level (e.g. an oracle)?

Comment: Better if I refer to sources: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/683

Comment: Spoofed seems to be incorrect here. Yes, there are criticism to its use, but spoofable is nowhere in the issue.

Comment: "Spoof" is the wrong word for a contract impersonating someone else to a contract that relies on `tx.origin`?

Comment: For completeness, you can even call a function within the same contract externally from another function with `this.myFunc()`, which allows you to change the message sender from account that signed the transaction to the contract itself. It's useful in certain situations for added security, where the initially called function has to run specific checks, which would then call another function. The function called by contract would, for example, restrict only owner of the contract or contract itself to call it. That is, it's not limited to behaving as a child or private function.

Comment: "when you're interested in the user identity but security isn't a concern" maybe for events that are only used on a front end to display user history or something ?

Comment: Is this answer still true in solidity versions 0.8.13 and up? I'm seeing that msg.sender is always the original transaction signer all throughout the chain of contract calls...

Answer (score 53):

`msg.sender` will be the contract calling the contract.

`tx.origin` will be the account that initiated the chain of contract calls.

Comment: To add to this: Inside a contract's constructor, `msg.sender` is the address that is deploying the contract.

Comment: Is this answer still true in solidity versions 0.8.13 and up? I'm seeing that msg.sender is always the original transaction signer all throughout the chain of contract calls...

Comment: Still true. It's the inner-most caller.

Answer (score 11):

Caller -> ContractA -> ContractB

Contract A is `msg.sender` in ContractB's case

Comment: Is this answer still true in solidity versions 0.8.13 and up? I'm seeing that msg.sender is always the original transaction signer all throughout the chain of contract calls...

Answer (score 3):

When you call a contract internally, the `msg.sender` is the original sender. In the contract below, the event which is emitted by the function `emitEvent` in the ChildContract emits the caller of the internal call and not the address of the contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract ChildContract {
    event CalledBy(address callee);
    function emitEvent() internal {
        emit CalledBy(msg.sender);
    }
}

contract Caller is ChildContract {
    function internalCall() {
        emitEvent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@Rinke Hendriksen:

This is so because when you deploy your code, there will never be a call between two contracts anywhere.

When you deploy the `Caller` contract on the Ethereum network it will also include the `ChildContract` code (as `ChildContract` is **base contract** for `Caller`), so basically you are calling a function that executes  another function of **the same contract.**

I advice you to read the **Inheritance** part of the Solidity documentation for the official explanation and more details.

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/contracts.html#inheritance